# Improving an iteration over a string in threes in Python

Tags: python, iteration, bioinformatics

I have to take a string input (in this case a DNA codon sequence) and print out the corresponding SLC's present in the sequence as an output(Eg input:ATT output:I). My current code can achieve this however I would like it to also cater for sequences that are not of a length divisible by 3 and output 'X' for those (eg input:ATTOP output:IX. Also is there a way for the results to be printed in one line as opposed to multiple lines?

```
DNA = 'GTTATCTTTPY'

def translate(DNA):
    if DNA == 'ATT' or DNA == 'ATC' or DNA == 'ATA':
        print 'I'
    elif DNA == 'CTT' or DNA == 'CTC' or DNA == 'CTA' or DNA =='CTG' or DNA == 'TTA' or DNA == 'TTG':
        print 'L'
    elif DNA == 'GTT' or DNA == 'GTC' or  DNA == 'GTA' or DNA == 'GTG':
        print 'V'
    elif DNA == 'TTT' or DNA == 'TTC':
        print 'F'
    elif DNA == 'ATG':
        print 'M'
    else :
        print "X"

for i in range(3, len(DNA) + 1, 3):
    translate (DNA[i-3:i])
```

output for above is:

V
I
F

so I would like the 'PY' to be outputted as 'X' as per else statement but its not of a length divisible by three. Also would like output to be : VIFX.

Comment: you could add the characters to a string then print that after the if..elif

Comment: It would help if you provided examples of inputs, the outputs you get right now and the outputs you expect.

Comment: Please see edit @Tagc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this is better to use `biopython` http://biopython.org/

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
seq = Seq('GTTATCTTT')
print(seq.translate())
```

you get,

```
VIF
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be probably better to put all possibilities that are connected to one output letter into a list and check whether your `DNA` variable is `in` such list. It just looks neater.

It could look like:

```
if DNA in ['ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA']:
    print 'I'
```

instead of:

```
if DNA == 'ATT' or DNA == 'ATC' or DNA == 'ATA':
     print 'I'
```

If you want to have all letters in one line, you could for example use a variable and simply add letters to it and print it after whole DNA code is analysed.

```
def translate(DNA):
    output = ''

    if DNA in ['ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA']:
        output += 'I'
    ...
```

To print 'X' when you get less than 3 letters or any other combination, it's probably better to use `while` loop.

Your code could for example look like that:

```
def translate(DNA)
    output = ''
    while DNA: #it's the same as while DNA != ''
        three_letters = DNA[:3] #you should come up with better name ;)
        DNA=DNA[3:]# in Python 3 this works even if DNA has less than 3 letters, hope it works in Python 2 too
        if three_letters in ['ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA']:
            output += 'I'
       ... #here code all elifs and else inside while loop

    print output
```

That way you only have to give arguments to your function to get the result, no external `for` loops or such are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that makes things mostly data-driven which is often a good thing because it makes things simpler to debug and maintain.

```
xlate_map = {
    'I': ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
    'L': ('CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG', 'TTA', 'TTG'),
    'V': ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
    'F': ('TTT', 'TTC'),
    'M': ('ATG')
}

# build a translation table from mapping
xlate_table = {}
for code, values in xlate_map.items():
    for value in values:
        xlate_table[value] = code

def grouper(n, sequence):
    """s -> (s0,s1,...sn-1), (sn,sn+1,...s2n-1), (s2n,s2n+1,...s3n-1), ..."""
    for i in xrange(0, len(sequence), n):
        yield sequence[i:i+n]

def translate(DNA):
    res = (xlate_table.get(seq, 'X') for seq in grouper(3, DNA))
    return ''.join(res)

print(translate('GTTATCTTTPY'))  # -> VIFX
```

Comment: Doesn't this do exactly what you wanted?